# How to use hls with another type of format instead of m3u8

Tags: javascript, mp3, m3u8, hls.js

**Background:** Some time ago I implemented `hls.js` on the page to get a radio stream. The source of the stream was in `m3u8` format -> https://xx.net/content/123/m3u8s/456.m3u8 but now a client is going to change it to the link https://xx.net/content/123/456.mp3

**Problem:** In this case hls doesn't work, because it expects `m3u8` file.

**Question:** Is there a way to convert the link to `m3u8` or implement a new library instead of hsl? Do you know how to handle it, maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it really is pointing at an MP3 stream, you no longer need HLS.js to handle it.  A normal audio tag will work just fine.

```
<audio src="https://example.com/content/123/456.mp3" preload="none"></audio>
```

Comment: Thanks @Brad. I've come to the same conclusion :)